# How to generate Non Minified Js in Webpack ( CRA )

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm working on React Project which is built by CRA and Webpack version is 3.8.1.
By default, In development mode, webpack does not create actual files.

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    paths.appIndexJs
  ],
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')
  }
}
```

In other words, I am not able to see static/js/bundle.js file.

I should be able to see bundle.js and all chunks which are available in the static/js/*.

How can I move these files in another location?

Comment: If you run the `build` command do you see them in _build/static_ directory? If yes, why do you need to see those files in development phase?

Comment: Hi @dubes, You are absolutely right but I want non minified files so that I can use these files for debugging purpose. 
My project is live and we know there is a minified file on the live server. Now I want to debug the same using Fiddler. Fiddler is a software which map files on server to files on local machine.

Comment: as far as I remember, CRA webpack server still exposes `sourceMaps` so you can debug it usually via browser dev tools... does that help? or are you trying to debug something else?

Comment: Let me give you my actual challenge. On live, I have a file named app.min.js. This is a compressed file and not understandable or difficult to understand. If there is a bug on live. In order to debug that issue, I use Fiddler. I have another file app.js which is non minified. By using this file I can easily understand where is the problem. What I do, I simply bind that app.min.js to app.js using fiddler. But in webpack configuration I am not able to generate non minified files.

Comment: 2 questions: are sourceMaps turned off in live site? Do you still use the CRA (`react-scripts` in your package.json) or has it been `ejected`?